# How to get index of clicked input autocomplete vuetify

Tags: events, autocomplete, vuetify.js

Sorry to post here but I'm having hard times to find out how to retrieve the index of the clicked element in vuetify autocomplete, with the goal to change one of the key of the object that match the clicked element.

I'm having a simple autocomplete with an array of items and i call a method on click

```
    <v-autocomplete  
    :click="onInputClicked"
    :items="items">
```

I used the :click of vuetify in their autocomplete API, that says :

> **Events** >
> click : Emitted when input is clicked

Then, what I would like is having the index of the element click so I could change a properties in my state that match the clicked element with index X

```
     state.filters[index].isSelected = !state.filters[index].isSelected
```

What I have tried :

- I tried to pass the event callback in my method and see what a `event.current.target` would give me, but its undefined
- I looked up online for like 1 hour but I haven't find anything this :/

Pretty sure I'm missing something simple... any help would be appreciated !
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have mixed up **props** and **events** in the v-autocomplete API.
Bound props are prefixed with `:` like `:items` in your code snippet, but to capture events you should prefix them with `@`. So in your case, try changing the component to:

```
<v-autocomplete  
    @click="onInputClicked"
    :items="items">
```

then, you can access the click event by adding it as an argument to `onInputClicked`:

```
onInputClicked(myClickEvent) {
  console.log(myClickEvent)
}
```

Comment: Simple mistakes... thanks !